# How to make a int not be used twice when it randomly generates them?

Tags: java, android

I've coded a simple quiz game for Android, and currently Im having troubles with making questions not appear after they've been shown, i.o. I dont want it to ask me the same question twice..

This is the method Im using

```
 private void QBegin() {
   /*
    * Gets a random question
    */
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    String[] types = { "Question one",
            "Question two", 
            "Question three", 
            "Question four",
            "Question five"};
    Random random = new Random();
    int qType = random.nextInt(types.length);
    question.setText(types[qType]);
    getAnswers(qType); //gets four answers
}
```

Im not sure if this will work but, what if I add something like

Edit : Doesn't work..

```
    int i = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(qType);
    i++;
    if(list.contains(qType) && i != types.length + 1){
        return;
    } else {
        answerCounter.setText("Hit the bricks pal, you're done..");
    }
```

On http://stackoverflow.com got told to , add smth like:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(types.length);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    if(!list.contains(qType)){
        // help please, as I have no idea on what I should be doing!
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate over at Stack Overflow: [Creating Random Numbers with No Duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040001/java-creating-random-numbers-with-no-duplicates)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are basically two different ways of doing this efficiently:

- Put the questions in a list
- Shuffle the list
- Loop through the list and show the questions

or:

- Put the questions in a list
- Pick a question to show by random
- Remove that question from the list
- Repeat until the list is empty

Answer (score 4):

The usual way is to start with something like an array of indexes, then shuffle those into (pseudo-) random order with something like the Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Another possibility is to use a random number generator whose range and period are exactly equal to the number of entries you need to shuffle. Offhand I don't remember any algorithms for finding a generator with a specified range and period though.